# obfuscate url on meta redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, encode

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.example.com">
```

Hi, how can i obfuscate the http://www.example.com (like doing something with string.fromcharcode [i know that's only available in script tags] or some other encoding) since chrome gets rid of the whole url?
I know it can be done through script tags `<script>document.location=String.fromCharCode()</script>` but i want to see how it can be done via meta tags.
Many thanks to anyone who can help :).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use an already "obfuscated" url via [bitly](https://bitly.com/) or [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/).
But why insist, doing it in the meta-tag?

Comment: I told you why, because //, http: and https: are removed by chrome.

Comment: I think Chrome only hides the protocol.  I can't confirm this at the moment, but Firefox does something similar.